# Chi-square test from gsl while integrating gives 0

Tags: c++, gsl, chi-squared

I'm trying to calculate the multiple integrant using gsl library but it seems endless because chisq value constantly equals 0. Here is my integrating method:

```
double Integr::Fgg(double x_val, double k_val){

    double result, error;
    double bound_up[] = {2*M_PI, 2*M_PI, k_max, k_max};
    double bound_down[] = {0,0,k_min, k_min};
    const gsl_rng_type *T;
    gsl_rng *r;

    struct f_params params = {x_val, k_val};
    gsl_monte_function Fgg = {&Integr::integrant_prot, 4, &params};
    size_t calls = 5000;
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    T = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);

    //warm up
    gsl_monte_vegas_state *s = gsl_monte_vegas_alloc(4);
    gsl_monte_vegas_integrate(&Fgg, bound_down, bound_up, 4, 1000, r, s, &result, &error);

    //integration
    do{
        gsl_monte_vegas_integrate(&Fgg, bound_down, bound_up, 4, calls/5, r, s, &result, &error);
    }while(fabs(s->chisq - 1.0)>0.5);

    gsl_monte_vegas_free(s);
    return result;
}
```

Can anybody tell my why this value isn't changing? Is there sth wrong with my code or with my gsl usage? I have to admit that I'm new with gsl.

[edit]
Integrand function:

```
double Integr::integrant_prot(double *args, size_t dim, void *params){

    struct f_params *fp = (struct f_params *) params;
    return Integr::integrantFgg(fp->x_val, fp->k_val, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
}
```

Comment: Try changing `s->verbose` to 65 and see what's going on.

Comment: I got some information about axes 0,1,2,3 and all outcomes from weight[] equal 0. How should I interpret it?

Comment: What is `Integr::integrant_prot`? Does it return a constant number?

Comment: It's a special function needed in vegas which wraps the integrand function. It returns a double. I will add it to my post.

Comment: The weight equaling zero is reminiscent of what happens when integrating a constant function (e.g. f(x) = 12.847). There is no variance and therefore the weights are all equal to zero.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense... thanks for help!